# Get notified when my custom notification is expanded in the statusbar

Tags: android, notifications

I've created a custom notification that is shown in the statusbar.
I need to know when the statusbar is expanded and the user see my custom notification.
I managed to do this with accessibility manager, but i want to do this without it.
Maybe be get notified when my notification gets the focus, or when the statusbar is opened.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised that this is possible with `AccessibilityManager`. It is certainly not possible without it. Those are not your widgets -- they are displayed by the OS in conjunction with the home screen. You will find out if the user taps on the notification drawer entry, and that's it.